# Dynamic loading JSON files when building

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a tree of JSON files with some schemas and would like to create a library with mapping `path -> schema`. The problem is that I cannot use variable that is a result of using `path.join` when calling `require`. Maybe example of what I want to achieve:

```js
const URLS = [
  '/register',
  '/login'
];

const URL_TO_SCHEMA_MAP = URLS.map(url => {
  const result = {};
  const schemaPath = path.join('schemas', url, 'schema.json');
  const schema = require('json-loader!./' + schemaPath);
  result[url] = schema;
  return result;
}).reduce((obj1, obj2) => Object.assign(obj1, obj2));
```

The "problem" is that if I create `schemaPath` manually, i.e. using `+` operator then it works. I don't know why because all "varialbes" are "const" here.

Comment: could you log this and tell me the output `path.resolve("json-loader!.", schemaPath)` and make sure that schemaPath doesn't start with `/` ?

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I don't know exactly what happened but now it works. It was probably because of creation of absolute path instead of relative (and the way webpack 4 handles paths)

Comment: People getting here might find it useful: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/